# Simple Registration page info is not added to database using localhost

Tags: php

When I use localhost, after filling out my registration form, it will not redirect to the 'success' page for some reason and there is nothing added to the database.
When I uploaded the files to a real host online, same result except the database does update with the new user.

I have been following step-by-step this php tutorials by Alex from phpacademy from here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5A50qmC7wFo

here is the php code:

```
<?php 
                if (isset($_GET['success'])  === true && empty ($_GET['success'])  === false){
                    echo '<h8>You\'ve been registered successfully.<br>Please check your email for a confirmation link.</h8>';
                    header("refresh:20;url=index.php");
                } else{

                    include 'regform.php'; //REGISTRATION FORM

                    if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true){
                        $register_data = array(
                        'first_name'    => $_POST['first_name'], 
                        'last_name'     => $_POST['last_name'], 
                        'username'      => $_POST['username'], 
                        'password'      => $_POST['password'],                          
                        'email'         => $_POST['email'],
                        'email_code'    => md5($_POST['username'] + microtime())
                        );
                        register_user($register_data);
                        header('Location: register.php?success');
                        exit();

                    } else if (empty($errors) === false){
                        echo output_errors($errors);
                    }
                }
            ?>
```

Comment: `success` has to equal something.

Comment: phpacademy, godaddy and 000webhost - not really your week, is it?

Comment: You are redirecting to the register page, not the success page.

Comment: I added Location: register.php?success=true and it seems to redirect, problem is now with the database, isn't it supposed to put the info in for the localhost just like it does for online host?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:
`header('Location: register.php?success=true');`

Comment: it seemed to work in terms of redirecting which is a good start. The database is still not updated with the info though :/

Comment: Can you please provide your `regform.php` file??

Comment: Okay, I'm not familiar with `register_user` function. What's about it?? Did you included it properly??

Comment: i had the stupidest mistake for the activation link and that's why it wasn't working. I had $ instead of &. I hate debugging sometimes :/